# how to add BEFORE to interface included directories for exported target?

Tags: cmake

I have a exported target A::A, there is a `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, `A_includes`.

```
set_target_properties(A::A PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${A_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

With old style I can add `BEFORE` to `target_include_directories` like following, to make sure the `A_includes` come before the system ones:

```
target_include_directories(
  some_target
  BEFORE
  PRIVATE
  ${A_includes}
)
```

But I want to use the modern style with the exported target:

```
target_link_libraries(
  some_target
  PRIVATE
  A::A
)
```

However, the modern one does not allow me to pass BEFORE. Is there any way to set the BEFORE during target exporting? Is there a way to make includes form A::A go before system one when I use it in a project?

Comment: You can still use the `BEFORE` keyword when populating the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of `A::A`, which get propagated to the consuming targets. What happens when you try this? Does it work?

Comment: @squareskittles I did not know it is possible. How do you put before in `set_target_properties`?

Comment: Any resolution on this one? @Kevin You can add `BEFORE` to `target_include_directories`, yes, but this only controls the order of dirs in `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, and doesn't make these dirs appear before other dirs for the target `some_target`...